# angular2 progress bar to show progressing with linear gradient color

Tags: angular, css, primeng

I am not experienced with designing UI. I am looking for a progress bar to show the progressing of http call. I want to implement as shown in the attachment. Can anyone help me with some example code to achieve this please?

I am using Primeng for designing the controls.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Hope this helps.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-progressbar

Answer (score 1):

You can go for ngx-progressbar. It will take data from http call. Hope this link helps. [here](https://medium.com/letsboot/lets-add-a-progress-bar-to-angular-4-apps-using-ngx-progressbar-45a2a1089d4e)

Comment: Thank you. It really help. But i am looking something similar to the one i have shown here.

Comment: Hi, is there a way to position the progress bar? right now it is fixed and the spinner is appearing at the center. I would like to have it on the right hand side.

Comment: `[spinnerPosition] = "right" ` can help you with that.

Comment: Yes. i tried that. but getting spineerPosition not a property of ng-progressbar. Also the progress bar appears at the top of the page instead at the location where i wanted to. Anyway to override this position? Thanks